# Yii2 - Query count per day to ActiveRecord

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have the following table structure and using Yii2 `ActiveRecord` methods I'd like to extract the number of bookings (`OrderLine`) a supplier has for each day for the next week (0 entries also required). So some way of getting a row per day per supplier, with `num_bookings` or potentially `0` depending on the supplier.

```
 /--------------------\                  /------------\
 | OrderLine          |------------------|Availability| 
 |--------------------| 0..n           1 |------------|
 |ID {PK}             |                  |ID {PK}     |
 |availabilityID {FK} |                  |start       |
 |line_status         |                  \------------/
 |supplierID   {FK}   |
 \--------------------/
          | 1
          |
          |
          | 1
     /----------\
     | Supplier |
     |----------|
     |ID {PK}   |
     \----------/
```

Querying the database directly, using DAO, with the following SQL gives me (almost) the desired result,

```
select count(ol.ID) as num_bookings, 
       day(from_unixtime(a.start)) as order_day,
       ol.supplierID
from order_line ol left join 
availability a on ol.availabilityID = a.ID
where ol.line_status = "booked"
and a.start >= 1451952000   //magic number for midnight today
and a.start <= 1452556800   //magic number for seven days from now
group by order_day, ol.supplierID;
```

something along the lines of

```
------------------------------------
| num_bookings|order_day|supplierID|
------------------------------------
| 1           | 5       | 3        |
| 2           | 5       | 7        |
| 1           | 6       | 7        |
| 1           | 7       | 7        |
------------------------------------
```

So there should be entries of `0` for the days the given `Supplier` has no bookings, like so

```
------------------------------------
| num_bookings|order_day|supplierID|
------------------------------------
| 1           | 5       | 3        |
| 0           | 6       | 3        |
| 0           | 7       | 3        |
| 2           | 5       | 7        |
| 1           | 6       | 7        |
| 1           | 7       | 7        |
------------------------------------  
[days 8+ omitted for brevity...]
```

I've got some php/Yii code which will [eventually] give me something similar but involves multiple queries and database connections as follows,

```
$suppliers = Supplier::find()->all(); // get all suppliers

$start = strtotime('tomorrow');
$end = strtotime('+7 days', $start);  // init times

// create empty assoc array with key for each of next 7 days
$booking_counts[date('D j', $start)] = 0;
for ($i=1; $i<7; ++$i) {
   $next = strtotime('+'.$i." days", $start);
   $booking_counts[date('D j', $next)] = 0;
}

foreach ($suppliers as $supplier) {
     $bookings = OrderLine::find()
                    ->joinWith('availability')
                    ->where(['order_line.supplierID' => $supplier->ID])
                    ->andWhere(['>=', 'availability.start', $start])
                    ->andWhere(['<=', 'availability.start', $end])
                    ->andWhere(['order_line.line_status' => 'booked'])
                    ->orderBy(['availability.start' => SORT_ASC])
                    ->all();

    $booking_count = $booking_counts;
    foreach ($bookings as $booking) {
        $booking_count[date('D j', $booking->availability->start)] += 1;
    }

}
```

This gives me an array for each supplier with the count stored under the appropriate day's index but that feels quite inefficient.

Can I refactor this code to return the desired data with fewer database calls and less 'scaffold' code?

Comment: i think you should use join() with supplier on behalf of foreach

Comment: i thought so, but i also need to access suppliers which have no bookings (OrderLines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be is the trasposition of your firt select

```
    $results = OrderLine::find()
        ->select('count(order_line.ID) as num_bookings, day(from_unixtime(availability.start)) as order_day', order_line.supplierID )
        ->from('order_line')
        ->leftjoin('availability', 'order_line.availabilityID = availability.ID')
        ->where( 'order_line.line_status = "booked"
            and a.start >= 1451952000   
            and a.start <= 1452556800')
        ->groupBy(order_day, order_line.supplierID)
        ->orderBy(['availability.start' => SORT_ASC])
        ->all();
```

in this way you should obtain a row for supplierID (and order_day) avoinding the foreach on supplier

For  getting the data in $results->num_bookings and order_day you need add

```
 public $num_bookings; 
 public $order_day;
```

in your OrderLine model

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for your attempt but it leaves me with the same problem as performing the query using DAO; namely it only returns a row for each day with bookings and not a row for each day for each supplier, regardless if a day has any bookings.

Comment: it seems strange because in the select and group by are both the date and supplier .. Check the value you are really using ..